# Difference between EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings and InformationRightsManagementSettings

Tags: csom, file, irm

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File` has above two properties. Can someone tell me details about them and difference between them.

According to my research, when IRM on a library is enabled, the details come in `EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings` but then what is the other one used for?

Answer (score 0):

By observing below to documentation it seems that `EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings` is `File` class property and provide details for document library and `InformationRightsManagementSettings` is `SPList` class property which provides details for SharePoint List.

1. [File.EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/mt683899(v=office.15)).
2. [SPList.InformationRightsManagementSettings Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.informationrightsmanagementsettings).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh but we have this too https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/mt683900(v=office.15) I am looking for difference between the two in File only